# Auto Increment in js with custom prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, express

I need to generate a username with prefix start from 00000,so first user should be MS00001 and if reach 100,000 user will be MS100000.

the lastcustomers is query

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id=(SELECT max(id) FROM customers)
```

My first idea is to query from my database and get the user id which have auto increment in mysql.

and +1 base on the return id in my input.

```
<% if(customers=="" ){ %>
      <div class="form-group">
              <label for="addMemberUsername">UserName</label>
               <input value="MS00001" type="text" class="form-control"
                name="addMemberUsername" placeholder="Username">
      </div>
 <% }else { %>
        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="addMemberUsername">UserName</label>
                <input value="MS0000<%= LastCustomers[0].id + 1 %>" type="text"
                 class="form-control" name="addMemberUsername"
                 placeholder="Username">
                 </div>
<% } %>
```

but this hard code cant change the 10th record to become MS000010,
how I make it to MS00010 and if reach 100,000 user will be MS100000.

Comment: Firstly, is there a reason you need to know the id at this point? The general pattern is to create the user first, then return the id of the new record in the save action. Secondly, be very careful storing your users with incremental ids. It makes it *very* easy for attackers to enumerate your data if you have any security issues.

Comment: **is there a reason you need to know the id at this point?**
I think no, I get the id is because my first idea is increment by the id
** be very careful storing your users with incremental ids.**
this will run in localhost so for now it's ok

Comment: *run in localhost* - However, also consider multiple users - if 2 people (or you with two pages/tabs) open the page at the same time, you'll both get the same "new" id and saving will fail or cause problems.

Comment: `I get the id is because my first idea is increment by the id` use `AUTO_INCREMENT` on your id field in the database. That way it will automatically assign the next value when a new record is created: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html. Note that this only works on numeric values, though.

Comment: Most of us come up with this idea when we are beginning our use of databases. But it does not take long to realise it is one of the worst idea's we are ever likely to have, in our whole lives. Dont do it, save yourself the pain. Think again

Comment: If you look around in here, you will find question from people who have done this asking how I can stop my system from creating duplicate Customer Numbers

Comment: @freedomn-m ohh thanks !  I really forget about this.
Will add another condition before I insert

but still my first question remain, how I generate a username like ms00001 and increment everytime when I insert a new user

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah I know, so I create another column: username and try to store MS0001 ++

Comment: This is what `PadLeft()` is for:  `value="MS<%= (LastCustomers[0].id + 1).ToString().PadLeft(6, '0') %>`

Comment: *user id which have auto increment* - if the user ID is auto-increment, then you won't be able to set it anyway, so your ID will easily get out of sync with your username - probably not a good idea.